# Embeding bmp in c++ using VS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.10.4. I've created a Win32 C++ app that displays a bmp picture. I've been trying to embed the picture into the complied .exe but not having success. My goal is to create the .exe without the need for any additional files or folders.

I did the following:

1. Right click on the App name in the Solution Explorer
2. Select Add from the dropdown and New Item from the popup box
3. Select Resource in the left column and Resource File(.rc) in the right column, then the Add button at the bottom
4. A pop up occurred:  warning RC4005: '_APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE':redefinition, select OK
5. In the Resource View, right click on Resource.rc and select Add Resource… at the bottom
6. Select Bitmap and select New
   There were a few more steps, but I lost track after trying to resolve the issue.

In the Solution Explorer under Resource Files I have Resource.rc and art1.bmp. For art1.bmp I have it so it is not excluded from the build. A resource.h file was also created.

resource.h has the following:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Resource.rc
//

#define IDB_BITMAP1                     103

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        104
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

In the .rc file, it has the following (and more)

```
IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "art1.bmp"
```

I have art1.bmp in the project root, Release folder and Debug folder.

After I compile the code into Release x86, the picture shows up without any issues (same in Debug) when I run the .exe. If I delete the picture from the Release folder, the picture no longer shows up.

Any suggestions on what step or steps I missed or what I need to change so the picture will be part of the .exe and not a seperate file?

Comment: How do you display the picture? Do you actually load it from the resource - do you use `IDB_BITMAP1` anywhere in your code? It sounds like your code doesn't use the resource, but reads a file on disk.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, You are correct. I did not have IDB_BITMAP1 in LoadImageA (using A instead of W for now). I added #include "resource.h" and went from:

 bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL, "art1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

to

 bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL, IDB_BITMAP1, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

I get the following errors:

Error (active) E0167 argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCSTR"
Error C2664 'HANDLE LoadImageA(HINSTANCE,LPCSTR,UINT,int,int,UINT)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'int' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: so I tried the following but get "Exception thrown at 0x776D0796 (ntdll.dll) in DesktopApp3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000067."

bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

At this point I'm thinking about creating a new project with my .cpp file and recreating the resource file. I'm thinking I might have made something dirty with all the changes I've been trying.

Comment: Why are you passing `LR_LOADFROMFILE` when you don't in fact want to load from file? Make it `LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik   Success! Can you try and explain how you knew to use GetModuleHandle(nullptr) instead of NULL? I went through the LoadImageA function documentation and the links for hours without success. I also read the page for GetModuleHandleA function and never figured out GetModuleHandle(nullptr). For UINT, I did try NULL, but since I did not have GetModuleHandle(nullptr), the function would not work. Now I see NULL for UINT actually works the same as 0.

Answer (score 1):

A big thank you to Igor, With his help, this issue is finally resolved.

My original code (which was not posted at the time) was:

```
bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL, "art1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Igor correctly asked "do you use IDB_BITMAP1 anywhere in your code?" which it was not.

I manage to get farther, but it still failed:

```
bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

I had tried replacing LR_LOADFROMFILE with NULL without success. The final key Igor provided was GetModuleHandle(nullptr) and NULL for UINT.

```
bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(GetModuleHandleA(nullptr), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, NULL);
```